# Encrypted ZFS replication on Debian (TrueNAS Scale)

Tags: linux, debian, zfs

I have a very simple system with one primary pool "tank" containing a single dataset "data".

A secondary pool "reservoir/data" is intended to hold replicated snapshots of "tank/data".

"tank/data" and "reservoir/data" are both encrypted datasets using different keys.

```
foo@BAR:~# zfs list -t snap | grep -v boot
NAME                                                                                                         USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
reservoir/data@auto-2020-11-24_20-50                                                                         258M      -     16.5T  -
tank/data@auto-2020-11-24_20-50                                                                             34.8G      -     16.5T  -
tank/data@auto-2020-12-01_00-00                                                                              128M      -     16.7T  -
tank/data@auto-2020-12-05_09-59                                                                             17.4G      -     16.8T  -
tank/data@manual-2020-12-06_21-12                                                                           46.7G      -     16.9T  -
```

I was able to do an initial replication via:

`zfs send "tank/data@auto-2020-11-24_20-50" | pv | zfs recv -Fdu "reservoir"`

But I have been unable to figure out how to replicate subsequent snapshots.

I run each send and recv through `pv` with `-n` dry run flag, and when I am able to get a replication stream going I can see that the amount of data being transmitted is far above what I would expect to be contained in an incremental and I abort it!

Errors:

`zfs send -R -I "tank/data@auto-2020-12-01_00-00" "tank/data@manual-2020-12-06_21-12" | pv | zfs recv -n -Fdu "reservoir"`

> cannot send tank/data@manual-2020-12-06_21-12: encrypted dataset tank/data may not be sent with properties without the raw flag

I've been poring over `man zfs-send` and have discovered the `-w` flag for raw replication streams but I'm struggling to make sense of things.

Transferring what appears to be too much data!

> zfs send -R -w -I "tank/data@auto-2020-12-01_00-00" "tank/data@manual-2020-12-06_21-12" | pv | zfs recv -n -Fdu "reservoir"

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the output of `zfs list reservoir` on your receiving host?

Comment: would the syncoid fail to sync? https://github.com/jimsalterjrs/sanoid/issues/635 (search for "so i have downloaded syncoid")